# Java "TRAP" Assertion Error

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I am writing a class for Spigot, that defines a lot of new crafting recipes. However, it seems that when I call an event, it sometime throws a `Assertion Error: TRAP`.
I have researched a lot, and find no useful tips, or anything.

Items.java

```
package com.myththewolf.omnomnom.lib;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.SkullType;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.SkullMeta;

public class Items {
    private static HashMap<ItemStack,Integer> items = new HashMap<ItemStack,Integer>();
    private static List<ShapedRecipe> itemC = new ArrayList<ShapedRecipe>();
    public ItemStack setMeta(ItemStack material, String name, List<String> lore)
    {
        if (((material == null) || material.getType() == Material.AIR) || ((name == null && lore == null)))
        {
            return null;
        }
        ItemMeta im = material.getItemMeta();
        if (name != null)
        {
            im.setDisplayName(name);
        }
        if (lore != null)
        {
            im.setLore(lore);
        }
        material.setItemMeta(im);
        return material;
    }

    public static void makeRecipies()
    {

            ItemStack skull; 
            skull = new ItemStack(Material.SKULL_ITEM, 1, (short) SkullType.PLAYER.ordinal());
            SkullMeta SM; 
            SM = (SkullMeta) skull.getItemMeta();
            SM.setOwner("MHF_CHEST");
            skull.setItemMeta(SM);
        addRecipie(3, "CCC", "BAB", "CCC", skull, Material.COOKED_BEEF, Material.BREAD, Material.AIR);
        for(ShapedRecipe sr : itemC)
        {
            Bukkit.getServer().addRecipe(sr);
        }
    }

    public static HashMap<ItemStack,Integer> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public static void addRecipie(int hung,String patA, String patB, String patC, ItemStack out, Material a, Material b, Material c)
    {
        ShapedRecipe rec = new ShapedRecipe(out);
        rec.shape(patA,patB,patC);
        rec.setIngredient('A', a);
        rec.setIngredient('B', b);
        rec.setIngredient('C', c);
        items.put(out, hung);
        itemC.add(rec);
    }
}
```

RightClickEvent.java

```
package com.myththewolf.omnomnom.event;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import com.myththewolf.omnomnom.lib.Items;

public class RightClickEvent implements Listener {
    @EventHandler

    public void onInteractEvent(PlayerInteractEvent e)
    {
        Action a= e.getAction();


        if(a == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK || a==  Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)
        {

            final HashMap<ItemStack,Integer> items = Items.getItems();
            if(items.containsKey(e.getItem()))
            {
                int foodL = e.getPlayer().getFoodLevel();

                e.getPlayer().setFoodLevel(foodL + items.get(e.getItem()));
                ItemStack hand = e.getPlayer().getItemInHand();
                int amount = hand.getAmount();
                if (amount > 1) {
                    hand.setAmount(amount - 1);
                    e.getPlayer().setItemInHand(hand);
                } else {
                    e.getPlayer().setItemInHand(new ItemStack(Material.AIR));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
[22:50:18 FATAL]: Error executing task
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: TRAP
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:47) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.D(MinecraftServer.java:739) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.DedicatedServer.D(DedicatedServer.java:399) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.C(MinecraftServer.java:675) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:574) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: TRAP
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemStack.F(ItemStack.java:86) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemStack.setCount(ItemStack.java:814) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemStack.add(ItemStack.java:818) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemStack.subtract(ItemStack.java:822) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemSkull.a(ItemSkull.java:79) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.ItemStack.placeItem(ItemStack.java:152) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:491) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:897) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:37) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PacketPlayInUseItem.a(PacketPlayInUseItem.java:1) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_11_R1.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:46) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-f950f8e-4f47972]
    ... 5 more
```

What exactly IS this error?

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Fixed.

Comment: related: https://hub.spigotmc.org/jira/browse/SPIGOT-2874

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are allowing a block that is due to be placed to be replaced with air in the player's hand. Placing air is impossible in Minecraft, so an `AssertionError` is thrown.

A solution would be to cancel the `PlayerInteractEvent`